# Visual Studio 2017 code correction suggestion shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017 and in the past I've used a keyboard shortcut to show a small list of suggested fixes for code errors.  I cant remember the shortcut could someone please tell me what this is?

And what would be the correct name for this feature?

Comment: EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.QuickActionForPosition - CTRL + .

Comment: Do you mean the [quick actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions) from the light bulb? (ctrl + .)

Comment: Yes that's the one.  Thanks.

Comment: (ctrl + .) is what I was looking for.  So I assume these are simply known as Quick Actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then <kbd>.</kbd> will display a list of Quick Actions with potential fixes.